# Unmet dependencies for vim-tiny package

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, vim

I tried some of the available solution, but hard luck anyone able to provide me the solution.

1. [Unmet dependencies installing vim or vim-tiny](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116106/unmet-dependencies-installing-vim-or-vim-tiny)
2. [Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1223066/unmet-dependencies-try-apt-fix-broken-install)
3. [How to fix unmet dependencies for udev:amd64 error on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097066/how-to-fix-unmet-dependencies-for-udevamd64-error-on-ubuntu-18-04)

```
sudo apt upgrade  
Reading package lists... Done   
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done 
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.   
The following packages have unmet dependencies:    
vim-runtime : Breaks: vim-tiny (2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1) but 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3 is   installed  
vim-tiny : Depends: vim-common (= 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3) but 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1 is installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried even re-installing & installing the `vim-tiny` but not able to do the same. it gives me the error

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall vim=2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
vim-runtime : Breaks: vim-tiny (< 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1) but 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3 is to be installed  
vim-tiny : Depends: vim-common (= 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3) but 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1 is to be installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am also attaching the output of `sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [110 kB]    
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports InRelease [101 kB]  
Get:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.8 kB]
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,476 B]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,288 B]
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]     
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [6,428 B]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,312 B]
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Fetched 363 kB in 2s (167 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

and `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done   
The following additional packages will be installed:  
  vim-tiny  
Suggested packages:  
  indent  
The following packages will be upgraded:  
  vim-tiny  
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.  
3 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/675 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y  
(Reading database ... 286916 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../vim-tiny_2%3a8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking vim-tiny (2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1) over (2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3) ...  
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/vim-tiny_2%3a8.2.2434-3ub
untu3.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/vim/vim82/doc/help.txt', which is also in package vim-runtime 2:8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/vim-tiny_2%3a8.2.2434-3ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix this error?

**UBUNTU :-** Ubuntu 21.10
**Windowing System :-** Wayland

Comment: Please add `apt-cache policy vim-runtime vim-tiny vim-common` and check your /etc/apt/sources.list if security and update repo is enabled.

Comment: Post the output of `sudo apt-get update` as well

Comment: post the output of `sudo apt --fix-broken install` too

Comment: To fix this you could `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`